# How to get values from the response of fix transport wso2

Tags: wso2, fix-protocol

I am new using wso2 for fix protocol.

I have setup wso2 Initiator as a proxy like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="FIXFastMatch3" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="fix://host:port?BeginString=FIX.4.2&amp;SenderCompID=Mycomp&amp;TargetCompID=mybroker&amp;SSLTunnel=NO">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </address>
    </endpoint>
    <inSequence>
        <property name="transport.fix.ServiceName" scope="axis2-client" type="STRING" value="FIXFastMatch3"/>
        <log level="full"/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <log level="full"/>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.fix.InitiatorConfigURL">file:/home/ec2-user/xxxx_server_new/FIXQuote.cfg</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.fix.SendAllToInSequence">false</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.fix.DropExtraResponses">false</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.fix.InitiatorMessageStore">file</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.fix.InitiatorLogFactory">console</parameter>
</proxy> 
<20200312-09:47:47, FIX.4.2:MyCOmp->mybroker, incoming> (8=FIX.4.29=015235=X34=749=mybroker52=20200312-09:47:47.60856=mycomp1262=VT_021268=01279=055=EUR/JPY269=1278=872415234270=116.94400271=0200000010=050)
```

but when i use example from wso2 my response are soap message but when i hit my broker my response not soap message. why like that ? and how to get the soap response in my issues ? i think there is any problem in my listener
My question is:

How to get values from fields 35, 270, and 52?

Comment: I corrected your grammar to make the content easier for people to read and understand at a glance. Please check if I correctly understood what you wanted to say - in a couple of places I was unsure. If I misunderstood somewhere you can use the EDIT link below the question to correct any mistakes.

Comment: thanks cindy meister. my question is why when i call via fix. my listener cannot response it as soap xml like another response. it is bug or something wrong with my config in wso2

Comment: did you solve this issue?